# javamail-androidでGmailのOAuthのトークンによる認証を行う方法を教えてください。

Tags: android, oauth, gmail

javamail-androidでGmailのOAuthのトークンによる認証を行う方法を教えてください。

詳細：
　お世話なっております。

http://kawaidesu.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/04/071658
　http://diary.syarihu.net/2015/05/androidandroidoauthoauthhelper.html
　上記のサイトを参考にさせて頂き「安全性の高いアプリ」として、gmailを介してメール送信を行いたいのですが難航しております。

Gmailのトークン習得までは進めたのですが、それをどのようにコードに組み込めばいいのかがわからず困っております。
　Webを調査して辿り着いた断片的なコードを組み合わせて試してはいるのですが動作せず途方にくれております。

ご存知の方がおられましたらアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか？
　よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labs閉鎖に伴ってコードが無くなったらしいですね。
検索したらいっぱい出てきましたが、
http://qiita.com/daisy1754/items/788cf32d9379746bba14
のサイトがご希望のものに近いかと思います。

Comment: sken2様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
上記のサイトを参考に動かすことができました。
ありがとうございました。